# n-install: ERROR: GNU Make not found, which is required for operation

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, n

Try to install `n` using [third-party-installers](https://github.com/tj/n#third-party-installers) on WSL (ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS). Got the below error:

```bash
lindu@LAPTOP-C8AFGSGK:~$ sudo curl -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/n-install/stable/bin/n-install | bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   161  100   161    0     0    373      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   373
100 43367  100 43367    0     0  45308      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  112k
n-install: ERROR:
  GNU Make not found, which is required for operation.
  On FreeBSD and PC-BSD, for instance, you can download it with `sudo pkg install gmake`.
```

And try to run the command from the error message, but got the error:

```bash
~$ sudo pkg install gmake
sudo: pkg: command not found
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation for [n-install](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install#installing-n), `make` needs to be installed.

> **Supported platforms and prerequisites**
>
> Among the platforms supported by n, any Unix-like platform with the following is supported:
>
> - bash
> - curl
> - git
> - GNU make

On ubuntu/ubuntu-wsl, the following can be executed to install the required dependencies

```bash
sudo apt-get install git curl make bash
```